# How to remove a number isolated amongst anothers

Tags: c, switch-statement

I'm having trouble with this: A bounce filter is an approach that allows one to get rid of the bounce effect, i.e.,
glitches/spikes like the ones in mechanical switches or in noisy sensors. Here we consider
bounce as a single 0 in the middle of some 1’s, or a 1 in the middle of some 0’s. There are
many ways to make a debouncer. Here we are interested in producing the desired effect
by a finite state automaton (in software). Accordingly, the automaton should remove a
0/1 isolated amongst 1’s/0’s.

And i have no idea how to remove a 0/1 isolated amongst 1’s/0’s inside a switch case. any ideas?

Comment: This probably doesn't answer your question but I wouldn't even use a `switch` `case` (as distinct from a mechanical switch) when there are only two options. I would examine the data and force an element to be the same as its two neighbours, if those neighbours equal each other. There will be a problem with very noisy data, though.

Answer (score 1):

As a satae machine:

```
S1 (out '1'):  
   '1' > S1  
   '0' > S2

S2 (out '1'):  
   '1' > S1  
   '0' > S4   

S3 (out '0'):  
   '1' > S1  
   '0' > S4   

S4 (out '0'):  
   '1' > S3  
   '0' > S4
```

translated to code (written on the fly, excuse syntax):

```
enum EState { Strong1, Weak1, Weak0, Strong0 };
EState m_state = Weak0;
bool stateStep(bool b) {
 switch(m_state) {
 case Strong1:
  if(!b) 
   m_state = Weak1
  break;
 case Weak1:
 case Weak0:
  m_state = b ? Strong1 : Strong0;       
  break;
 case Strong0:
  if(b) 
   m_state = Weak0
  break;
 }
 return (m_state==Strong1) || (m_state==Weak1);
}
```